# Android Drive API startResolutionForResult returns RESULT_CANCELLED

Tags: android, drive

I'm trying to implement Google Drive to my Android app and I cannot even connect to Api client. And I don't know why:

1. I have configured project and credentials in developer console for ~/.android/debug.keystore (values seems to be correct)
2. I have copy-pasted code from [Drive for Android Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) -> In method `onConnectionFailed()` I'm calling `connectionResult.startResolutionForResult()` if `connectionResult.hasResolution()`
3. In `onActivityResult` for matching `requestCode` I'm receiving `resultCode == 0` (RESULT_CANCELLED) even when i select my account

Do you have any idea why? I also tried to add:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
    android:value="----"/>
```

into Manifest which is not mentioned on documentation page but on some SO posts.

Thanks for help

**Edit:**

I have also tried to use `enableAutoManage`

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .build();
```

instead of manualy configuring connection and connectionFailed callbacks:

```
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
```

It returns me error code 13 in `onConnectionFailed` method. Based on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#CANCELED) it seems, that this returns when:

> OnConnectionFailedListener passed to
>   enableAutoManage(FragmentActivity,
>   GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) when the user choses not
>   to complete a provided resolution. For example by canceling a dialog.

But i didn't cancelled it.

I'm testing it on Nexus 5x - Android N

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found where the problem was while reading something about wallet api

I've just needed to create OAuth client ID not API key

1. Go to [Developer Console > Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Click "create credentials" > OAuth client ID > Android
3. Fill the details
4. Create
5. Open OAuth consent screen (on Credentials page)
6. Fill email and product name
7. Save

Now it works!

Comment: I have the same problem but doesn't understand how to fix it. I've created ClientID and even added google-services.json file to app but it doesn't seem to be enough. should I add anything in manifest file? or is there anything I have to do in my mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

***JUST IN CASE***

@VizGhar solution is right if you missed up Client ID creation process. But I get resultCode=0 and everything was fine with my OAuth client ID. And finally I **solved it**, so I created SHA1 as per documentation, but I run my app in debug mode (Build variant) and always had resultCode=0. Just **switched to release mode** and problem is gone, now resultCode=-1 as expected.

Comment: problem with you app/build.gradle maybe? Does your debug and release variants have same application id?

Comment: Sounds like you may have missed to register the SHA-1 of your debug keystore in the Google console?